# Two-ways route functionality

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

When clicking a tab in my Backbone app the routes work as expected and render the appropriate view:

```
switchView: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get clicked tab
    var target = $(event.currentTarget);

    // Tab is already selected - do nothing
    if (target.parent().hasClass('selected')) {
        return;
    }

    // First remove selected status on all tabs
    this.$el.find('li').removeClass('selected');

    // Then select the clicked tab
    target.parent().addClass('selected');

    // Switch to new view
    var fragment = target.attr('href').split('#');
    Backbone.history.navigate(fragment[1], true);
}
```

What I'm wondering is how I can cause the same functionality when writing a matching URL in the address bar? E.g. `mydomain.com/app.html#section/about` causes the "About" tab to be highlighted. Maybe I'm overlooking something, and perhaps the above is madness and not best practice at all.

Attaching a mockup of the app:

[image]

Comment: last time I checked there was no `navigate` method for `Backbone.History`. You should be calling the `navigate` method on your `Backbone.Router` instance

Comment: @nEEbz, `Backbone.history` has a `navigate` method. `Router.navigate` calls it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your tab links look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#section/home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section/products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

You should not catch the `click` event of the navigation links, i.e. remove your `switchView` and the associated event binding.  Instead you should let `Backbone.history` catch the hash change and trigger the route.

To implement the tab change behavior, you can then subscribe to the `route` event in your view. This will handle the tab changes triggered by your tab links, as well as other URL changes.

```
var TabView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(Backbone.history, 'route', this.onRouteChanged);
  },

  onRouteChanged: function() { 

    //get current url hash part
    var hash = Backbone.history.getHash();

    //find the link that has a matching href attribute
    var $activeTab = this.$("a[href=#'" + hash + "']");

    //if route matched one of the tabs, update tabs.
    if($activeTab.is("a")) {

      // First remove selected status on all tabs
      this.$('li.selected').removeClass('selected');

      // Then select the clicked tab
      $activeTab.parent().addClass('selected');
    }
  }
});
```

//code sample not tested